# How to save an unknown amount of data in memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, posix, mmap

I posted previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76461578/how-can-i-allocate-and-manage-my-own-heap-not-dynamically-allocating), but based on the comments, I had the wrong idea. Here is my question clearly: when reading from a stream, with an unknown amount of bytes coming in, what is the best way to save the data in memory to use at a later point?

Here are some ideas I have had:

- `mmap` a non-conflicting region of memory, and `mmap` some more as necessary (downside: possibly annoying to manage)
- create a linked-list structure of buffers, filling each before allocating the next (possibly easy to manage, given I write the API)
- allocate (on the stack) an array of pointers to such buffers (say 100, allocated using `malloc`) and hope that you don't have more than (100 * buffer size) worth of data to read (the easiest but least robust solution)

My idea, that the other post heavily rejected was:

- mess with `sbrk` and `brk` and do my own contiguous heap (which could then conflict with `malloc` and anyone that uses `malloc` -- though I personally wouldn't mind this since I only use the APIs in `unistd` for this application, and it is a learning project)

Is there a standard method (or even a specific function) for attacking this specific problem: an unknown amount of data needs to be read and saved in memory, how do you save it?

Comment: I just answered something similar: [Avoid allocating a large amount of memory for concatenation in C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76477992/5382650)

Comment: From what i understand of this and your previous question, it seems that `realloc` is your best bet here. Either implement a single buffer (reallocate if necessary), a list of buffers (reallocate pointer buffer for each new chunk, then for each chunk `malloc` a new region) or before you run out of memory, a ring buffer would be the better choice (same as the second option but in this case, you overwrite older entries - of course only if that  is an option, otherwise you have to think to swap data out into a file or something).

Comment: Why messing around with `brk` and `sbrk` if `malloc` and friends does that already and presumably much better than you could.

Comment: If you were doing this in C++ or golang or another modern language with collections like lists or vectors, you'd want one that uses something like a linked list (otherwise there would be too much overhead copying and resizing a buffer). I'd suggest the same for C, use a linked list (no language standard, but so many examples to copy from).

Comment: Re: "Why messing around with ..." Mostly because I wanna learn how to do it. I'm planning to also write my own `malloc` implementation at some point, but this is not that @ErdalKüçük. I am a student in uni. Seems like `realloc` would be a good option since large reads > buffer size are probably not a common case (but I've learned to always strive for robustness). I'll either try that out or implement a linked list ... thanks for your comment. Also @John Bayko as well, I know of `TAILQ` and some others, but like to always write my own (for now) for the practice, which is why I use C.

Comment: I see, you want to make your hands dirty ... have fun!

Comment: @user129393192, Use "create a linked-list structure of buffers, filling each before allocating the next ".  The goal of _contiguous_ is not really that valuable.

Comment: If contiguous is an important goal, then: mmap/mremap, or malloc/realloc. But, "unknown amount of bytes coming" contradicts "memory storage", or you have an upper bound?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I'm just reading from stdin, so the upper bound could be infinity ... but obviously that's not realistic. I'm likely gonna do the malloc/realloc for this specific use.